# How is "Global-DataTransfer-Regional-Byte" transfer calculated?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ec2, aws-cost-explorer

I started a EC2 t2.micro instance in  Canada(Central) region. I've installed WireGuard and Pi-hole in it. Upon VPN Connection, I did some network test using iperf3 between my computer and the instance. I also did that without connecting to WireGuard by using instance's Public ip.

I think this accounted to the 1GB "Global-DataTransfer-Regional-Byte" charge. But the documentation says it is data transfer  between Availability Zones in same Region.

How come what I've done relates to that?

Billing AWS Free Tier:
[image: Billing AWS Free Tier]

Comment: Does your billing console actually say you've *used* regional transfer? Your screenshot tells you that you *can* use that much, not that you *have*.

Comment: Use AWS Cost Explorer to work out costs.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes, it does. Updated the screenshot.